# send different messages to different email accounts using SMTP PHPMailer

Tags: php, mysql, email, smtp, phpmailer

I want to send different messages to different email accounts fetched from my Database,
The email can be up to 100 emails fetched from Database and messages must be different for each email account,
I tried this Code But unfortunately it sends one message to the first user only.
What I made wrong in this code please help me, Thank you.

```
<?php
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;  
  require 'class/src/Exception.php'; 
  require 'class/src/PHPMailer.php'; 
  require 'class/src/SMTP.php'; 
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host     = 'mail.company.com';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = 'help@company.com';
            $mail->Password = '****************';
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $mail->Port     = 465;
            $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
            $mail->setFrom('help@company.com', 'CompanyName');
            $mail->Subject = "Common Header of all of the Emails";
   $fetch_data = $conn->query("SELECT name, email FROM db_table WHERE status = 'Active'");
   foreach ($fetch_data as $fetched_data) {
   $name = $fetched_data['name'];
   $email = $fetched_data['email'];
  //========================= SEND IN FOREACH LOOP =========================>
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
            $mail->Body = " <h3>Hi $name,</h3><h4>Congrats!</h4>";
            $mail->send();
            $mail->ClearAllRecipients();  //  $mail->clearAddresses(); NOT WORKING
}
  ?>
```

Comment: Check the results of your query separately - make sure you are actually finding more than one record. How exactly is `clearAddresses` not working? For reference, look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Comment: I found the problem was there was only one email fetched from DB, Now It works cool, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion for debugging.

```php
<?php

$fetch_data = $conn->query("SELECT name, email FROM db_table WHERE status = 'Active'");
print_r($fetch_data); // Do you have all row you need
   foreach ($fetch_data as $fetched_data) {
   print_r($fetched_data); // Do you have all row you need
   $name = $fetched_data['name'];
   $email = $fetched_data['email'];
  //========================= SEND IN FOREACH LOOP =========================>
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
            $mail->Body = " <h3>Hi $name,</h3><h4>Congrats!</h4>";
            $mail->send();
            $mail->ClearAllRecipients();  //  $mail->clearAddresses(); NOT WORKING
}
```

Comment: I can't Thank enough, with  your code this `print_r($fetched_data); // Do you have all row you need`  I found the problem was there was only one email fetched from DB, Now It works cool, Thank you so much, You saved my day.